# Specific date in advance

Tags: android, date

Is there any easy way or a function to get what will be the date two weeks in advance? For example what will be the date after two weeks from now. I have checked Date() function and it doesn't look to have this functionality. The only way I can think of now is to hard code it, but I was hoping someone knows a better approach.

Comment: How about a `Calendar` object? You can pass to it your date via a `setTime` method and it has an `add` method, which will achieve what you want. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll post this as an answer.

This question has already an answer here: [How to add 7 days to current date while not going over available days of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654151/how-to-add-7-days-to-current-date-while-not-going-over-available-days-of-a-month)

You need to use the `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Joda Time Lib.](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 
i found something may help you using this lib [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728511/3713967)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +14);
Log.d("Date two weeks in advance is ",""+cal.getTime());
```